# Changing/removing the background color for the active window in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, powerline, selected-window

I use spacemacs on Emacs 28.1. The problem I am having is that in the modeline of the
emacs window, the unique window number is displayed. But the color being used to highlight the active window is yellow, and it is impossible to see a white digit against a yellow background.

[image]

How would I remove that yell background behind the number 1? For the non-active windows, there is no background and I can see the white numbers against the black background.